# Jetpack navigation force show back arrow

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I would like to know if it is possible to force a back arrow to show. Here's my use case:

1. main module with a list
2. detail screen (dynamic feature module)

Now in this details screen, I would like to know if it is possible to **force** a back arrow to show (and actually poping the activity out).

The details module has

1. Activity with...

   X amount of fragments (view, create, edit)

I would like all of these to be considered as top-level **but** unlike most q&a here on SO to always show the back button.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You shouldn't show a back arrow for the Activity itself. It's against the guidelines: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#the_up_button_never_exits_your_app

Comment: That has nothing to do with an Activity. Did you read the whole question? Thanks for your input and time.

Comment: ah, now I understand what you mean; your detail screen is a separate Activity. But in that case, if you navigate there through a deep-link, then Navigation AAC should know that you are on a *second* Activity destination, and should already be showing an UP button.

Comment: Exactly! That's the hard thing I'm trying to achieve, as the nav component was built with single activity in mind, I was wondering a way to do this :)

Comment: Maybe you are missing `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY` metadata: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-navigation-components-part-3-19554ec9ae83

Comment: did you solve it? @JoaquimLey

Comment: Sadly I wasn't able to consistently solve it, I tried to force it to show via the Activity but when the user navigated to another subgraph and get back to the original the arrow would be gone :|. But I would look into the new DynamicFeature capabilities of the Navigator library.